# The function $f$ is continuous if $f^2$ and $f^3$ are continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Prove or disprove: The function $f$ is continuous if $f^2$ and $f^3$ are continuous. Here $f^k(x) = f(x)^k$.

I defined $g(x)=x^{1/3}$ where $g$ is defined from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Is there any role of $f^2$ in solving the question

Comment: No, $f^2$ seems to be there just to confuse you. The $f^3$ is actually necessary. For example look at $f=1_{[0,\infty[}-1_{]-\infty,0[}$, we have that $f^2$ is continuous but $f$ is not.

Answer (score 3):

In order to prove that $\;f\;$ is a continuous function it is only necessary that $\;f^3\;$ is continuous.

Since the function $\;g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}\;$ is continuous on $\;\left]-\infty,+\infty\right[\;,\;$ by applying the theorem of continuity of composite function, we get that

$g\left(f^3(x)\right)=\sqrt[3]{f^3(x)}=f(x)\;$ is continuous.